# Is there way to embed third party js and html in react app

Tags: reactjs

For example we want to create a field for admins of the app where they can embed scripts of mailchimp or mailer lite or paste Facebook pixels or Google analytics pixel.

We tried the dangerousInnerHTML part but getting an error as the main script reference from third party is not executed I guess.

Wondering if any one has achieved this before

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue at all, but it sounds like the way you implement it is likely to be problematic. Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: Thanks @Terry. Here is a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamichtmljsreactcontainer-2p2p48?file=/src/App.js. Basically I am tryiing to see if the app user can copy and paste a third party script like email service popup or google analytics pixel. The app should later render it. In this case, its just an alert box and console.log that is being set